# How to monitor CellBracket evaluation state

Tags: front-end, dynamic, gui-construction, monitoring

Setting `SynchronousUpdating` to `False` or `Automatic` in GUIs may send calculations to the kernel and the `CellBracket` wrapping the GUI changes its appearance as evaluations take place, from highlighted/busy to plain/idle state.

I would like to know if there's a system variable or function I can use to track that busy/idle  state of cells.  I'm only interested in built-in functions to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, it does not only mean the evaluation takes place in the kernel but that it uses the Main Link.

Anyway, you can use `` FrontEnd`CellInformation `` or `` Developer`CellInformation `` which is translated to `` FrontEndExecute @ FrontEnd`CellInformation `` I guess.

```
Dynamic[
  { RandomInteger[10]
  , First /@ Select[
      {#, Developer`CellInformation[#]} & /@ Cells[]
    , Lookup[#[[2]], "Evaluating", False] &
    ]
  }
, UpdateInterval -> .1, TrackedSymbols :> {}
]

Button[1, Pause[2], Method -> "Queued"]
```

[image]

Comment: Implementing a solution to the real problem I have was possible using CellInformation as you suggest.  However, it would be way much more efficient if we could identify a system variable that can be used as an argument in TrackedSymbols instead of the UpdateInterval you suggest.  Thoughts?